# Filter by Date Range in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

The filtering in Google Spreadsheets seems to only offer text based solutions.

Is there any ability to filter cells by date ranges like any of the following:

- Today
- Yesterday
- Last Week
- Since 1/1/2015
- Between 1/1/2015 - 2/1/2015

Here's an example of the filtering options on a column that contains dates:

[image: screenshot]

A couple of workarounds would be to:

1. Format the dates so that they were `YYYY-MM-DD` so they showed up in the right order.
2. Use the [`=Filter()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) function [like this](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/MNLXrVFNljQ/LYgqFMIiyH4J):

   ```
   =FILTER(A:C,A:A>=TODAY(),A:A<=TODAY())
   ```

   But that requires adding a new sheet and manually updating the filtered values.
   I'd much prefer a solution that uses the built in [filter feature](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681)

Comment: I could have sworn they used to have this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Today Google added filtering conditions to Google Sheets.

<s>At this time the filter feature of Google Sheet doesn't include date range filtering</s>.

**References**
[Filter you data - Docs editors help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681)
[Google Sheets: Do more with your data - Google Docs Blog](http://googledocs.blogspot.mx/2015/06/google-sheets-do-more-with-your-data.html)